# Include roles in Service Account creation via Deployment Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

In the current Google Cloud Deployment Manager documents.. Seems like you can not create any roles or permissions with it or am I just missing a property or resource type?

Answer (score 0):

You must grant your project's Google APIs service account the primitive roles/owner role so it can apply the [IAM policies](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/set-access-control-resources#before-you-begin) you define in your configurations. And, When you create or update your deployment, Deployment Manager calls the Identity and Access Management (IAM) API to set the appropriate permissions on the resource.

I invite you to take a look at this [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710548/google-deployment-manager-assigning-iam-policies-at-project) thread to get more information.

Comment: oh sorry I am not aware of the `action`. I was only aware with the `type` as they don't show such examples in their document

Comment: You can find more information regarding deploymentmanager samples [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2)